# Inputs Fields don't show text in safari only

Tags: html, css, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

I have gone through various posts on stackoverflow and can't find any solution, I'm desperate already.

I have two entries for email and password, they work correctly in Chrome and Firefox but in Safari you don't see the placeholder or the text when typing

I have tried with the following properties:

```
#tp-user-loginlr2bdd0187 .tp-field-group input#userlr2bdd0187,
#tp-user-loginlr2bdd0187 .tp-field-group input#passwordlr2bdd0187{

    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -ms-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: textfield;

    color: #666666!important;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #bfbfbf;

    -webkit-text-fill-color: #666666;
    -moz-text-fill-color: #666666;
    -ms-text-fill-color: #666666;

    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -ms-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

Besides that I have used:

```
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;

    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;

    or 

    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -ms-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: textfield;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
```

I have also used just user-select or just appearance to check for overwrite issues and nothing works. I need to fix this as it is on the login page, could you please give me a hand.

Attached image of the problem: [image]

The rest of the properties that the Inputs have are:

```
     font-family: "Gotham Medium", Sans-serif;
     width: 100% !important;
     text-align: left;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     max-width: 100%;
     padding: 10px 15px;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, because in WordPress I had added `height: 0;` for a input.

For keep `height: 0;`, I had to add `line-height: 0;`

And it works on all browsers (;